# What does "32bit apps running in WOW only" means?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, visual-basic

I'm trying to run an application made with Visual Basic 6.0 on a Windows 7 64 bit edition.

The application is asking me for the DLL `vb6es.dll`. I have copied this file from a Windows XP into the `C:\Windows\system32` directory, but I continue getting the same error.

Searching on Google, I found the [support statement of visual basic 6.0 on windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms788708.aspx) and it says "32bit apps running in WOW only" for Windows 7 64 bit editions. What does this mean?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For common user nothing.

Problem with windows for quite some time is that it can only directly run programs for number of bits it was written. Therefore Windows on Windows system was developed which allowed 16bit programs to run on 32bit windows.

Same system is used for 64 bit windows too. WOW now supports 32bit application on 64bit system. Unfortunately, they got rid of 16bit WOW in the process.

From user's point of view, there is almost no performance difference and almost all applications will run on WOW as well as on native windows. In fact WOW runs so great that most users don't even know it's there.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_on_Windows)'s a link to Wikipedia article for old WOW and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WOW64)'s the article for new WOW.

Comment: Hi AndrejaKo,  I found the solution. I needed to copy the missing DLLs to directory called c:\windows\SysWOW64 . That's what you said right? Are binaries for WOW stored here?

Comment: @Kiewic  Yes, WOW should be stored there.